# Input field not rendering dash

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I'm noticing odd behavior with one of my inputs that I'm hoping someone could help with.

The below field is a dash delimited name.  In this instance I called it `jacobs-fishing-supply-birmingham`.  This is the exact value stored in my database.  I'm rendering it to the page via the php framework **laravel**.

When I view the html rendered I can see that php did its job in creating the input field with the dash:

```
<input id="handle" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" aria-label="" 
    aria-describedby="" value="jacobs-fishing-supply-birmingham">
```

However the browser isn't renders all but one dash...

[image]

So then I added a second version of the field for debugging purposes and the dash appeared on the second instance of the field:

[image]

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  The only thing I could think of is some sort of character set issue with that specific dash, however, it's strange that the dash appears when I add the same input a second time to the page.

Comment: Is the dash a hyphen, mdash, ndash, or something else? Try `ord` to see what you have. I'm also unclear where you are seeing the different displays, one is in the source and one is with the developer console?

Comment: Thanks.  The display are the input fields being rendered via Google Chrome.

Comment: Can you clarify when you get the different displays? Also what is the actual display (please use the `view source` option)?

Comment: @user3783243 I consistently see the input field as highlighted above.  The input field I provided is what is in the html presented by view source.

Comment: I corrected this by modifying the id from #handle to #handle-tag.  I identified jquery was the cause by disabling all scripts connected to the page.  When I removed jquery.js, the dash appeared.  

This either indicates I have a jquery script that's updating all #handle selectors, or jquery uses handle as a special identifier.  I'll dig more later and give the full root cause.

Comment: Okay, that would indicate you were viewing the source in the developer console, not the real source. In the future you should view the real source first (`command` + `option` + `u` in Chrome on a mac), then the developer console. The console will show modifications JS has made to your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my own.  I had an older jquery function nested within another javascript file that referenced the id selector #handle.